# How to load data in one2many field in openerp

Tags: openerp-7

I have created a custom module in Openerp . In the form view i have put the one2many field  to display the previous records .

The one2many field is on one model "sic_client_detail"

But am not able to display the data in one2many field . What extra thing needs to be done .

In Py file :

```
class si_client_details(osv.osv):

_name = 'si_client_details'
_columns = {
    'name' : fields.char('Employee No.'),
    'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', "Employee", required=True),

    'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Previous Company'),
    'project': fields.char('Project Name' , required=True),
    'indate': fields.date("Start Date"),
    'outdate': fields.date("End Date"),
    'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Current Company', required=True),
    'indate1': fields.date("Start Date", required=True),

    'pstatus': fields.selection([('bench', 'Bench'),('open', 'Not Started'),('progress', 'Project InProgress'),('close', 'Project Completed'),('abort', 'Project Aborted')],  'Project Status' , required=True),
    'address_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Working Address'),
    'comment': fields.text('Remarks', size=64),
    'current_datetime': fields.datetime('Current Date', size=64),
    'employee_line': fields.one2many('si_client_details', 'si_client_id', 'Historical Entries', size=64),
    'si_client_id':fields.many2one('si_client_details','Si Client Details'),

    'state': fields.selection([('draft', 'New'),('cancelled', 'Refused'),('confirm', 'Waiting Approval'),('accepted', 'Approved'), ],
                 'Status', track_visibility='onchange')
```

In Form View i have:

```
<field name="employee_line" widget="one2many" colspan="4" nolabel="1" domain="[('state','=','draft')]"/>
```

Comment: I think there is small bug in field declaration size=64 is not for one2many fields.
You should write,

'employee_line': fields.one2many('si_client_details', 'si_client_id', 'Historical Entries'),